# Process bar in VBA not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that converts/creates sheets based on a data sheet in a workbook. Depending on the data sheet, there can be anywhere between 3 to 50 new sheets created. When there's only data for three sheets it runs fairly quickly but when I have data for 50 new sheets, it takes a bit of time and I want to let the user know how quickly the process is - hence the status/process bar. I've used Ejaz' [approach](http://strugglingtoexcel.com/2014/03/27/progress-bar-excel-vba/) and uploaded the userform as well as the module to my workbook. I've tried to combine it with my code, which looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub convert_click()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, wsShift As Worksheet
Dim lRow&, mRow&
Dim shift$, person$, day$, desc$, typee$, shiftName$
Dim sRow&, sCol&
Dim oFind As Range
Dim bNedfald As Boolean, newCol$

newCol = FrontSheet.Range("FP_Column")
If newCol = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please specify column", vbCritical
    FrontSheet.Range("FP_Column").Activate
    Exit Sub
End If

LogSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Linenumber").Range(1, 1).Offset(0, 1) = newCol
LogSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Linenumber2").Range(1, 1).Offset(0, 1) = newCol

newCol = IIf(newCol = "EU", "M", "N")

' delete existing sheets before creating new one
Call deleteShiftSheets

START

Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")

With wsMaster
    If wsMaster.FilterMode Then wsMaster.ShowAllData
    lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    For mRow = 2 To lRow
        ' read data from master
        shift = Trim(.Cells(mRow, "A"))
        shiftName = IIf(.Cells(mRow, "F") = "", .Cells(mRow, "E"), .Cells(mRow, "F"))
        desc = Trim(.Cells(mRow, "B"))
        person = Trim(.Cells(mRow, "C"))
        day = Trim(.Cells(mRow, "D")) + 1
        typee = UCase(Trim(.Cells(mRow, "E")))
        sCol = person + 2
        sRow = (day * 8)

        ' get reference of existing sheet or create new one
        Set wsShift = getWorksheet(ActiveWorkbook, shift, desc)

        If InStr(1, desc, "nedfald", vbTextCompare) Then
            bNedfald = True
        End If

        If wsShift.Cells(7, sCol) = "" Then
            TemplateSheet.Range("Block").Copy
            'wsShift.Cells(7, sCol).PasteSpecial
            wsShift.Cells(7, sCol).Insert xlShiftToRight
        End If
        If wsShift.Cells(7, sCol) = "" Then wsShift.Cells(7, sCol) = person

        ' popualte data from master to shift sheet
        wsShift.Cells(sRow, sCol) = shiftName
        wsShift.Cells(sRow + 1, sCol) = .Cells(mRow, "H")  
        wsShift.Cells(sRow + 2, sCol) = .Cells(mRow, "I")    
        wsShift.Cells(sRow + 3, sCol) = .Cells(mRow, "J")    
        wsShift.Cells(sRow + 4, sCol) = .Cells(mRow, "L")    
        wsShift.Cells(sRow + 5, sCol) = .Cells(mRow, "K")
        wsShift.Cells(sRow + 6, sCol) = .Cells(mRow, newCol)    
        wsShift.Cells(sRow + 7, sCol) = .Cells(mRow, "O")    

Call modProgress.ShowProgress(0, wsShift, _
                "Excel is working on Task Number 1", False, _
                "Progress Bar Test")

    Next
End With

Call ignoreErrors
Call addButtons
Call protectSheets
Call validateRules
Call hideBlankPartStay


If Not bNedfald Then
    Call getWorksheet(ActiveWorkbook, "nedfald", "nedfald")
End If

FrontSheet.Activate
FINISH

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

''MsgBox "sheets generated", vbInformation
End Sub


' this function either retuns existing worksheet if already exists or create a new one and then return it
Function getWorksheet(wbFile, sheetName$, desc) As Worksheet
    Dim t As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo Sheet_Not_Found
    sheetName = sheetNameSafeString(sheetName)
Set getWorksheet = wbFile.Sheets(CStr(sheetName))
Exit Function

Sheet_Not_Found:
    TemplateSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    ' add new shift sheet
    TemplateSheet.Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    TemplateSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Set getWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Range("ShiftName") = sheetName
    ActiveSheet.Range("Description") = desc
    ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = -4142
    ActiveSheet.Name = sheetName
' this identifies it as shift sheet.
ActiveSheet.Range("Z1") = "Shift_Sheet"
DoEvents: DoEvents

If desc = "nedfald" Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("shTransfer").Delete
End If
End Function

' delete existing shift sheets.
Sub deleteShiftSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Range("Z1") = "Shift_Sheet" Then
        ws.Delete
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

When I run the macro it gives me this error:

"Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"

And is highlighting the following line:

```
Call modProgress.ShowProgress(0, wsShift, _
                "Excel is working on Task Number 1", False, _
                "Progress Bar Test")
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I have used Ejaz' code in the modProgress module as it is. Should I upload it here?)

Thx!

Comment: Declare the variable.

Comment: To start, you're not using the right arguments.  The second argument is expecting the number of total actions NOT a worksheet object.

Comment: modProgress but what sous said too if true. I didn't look into the class.

Comment: @findwindow, I'm not sure I understand. I have to declare the sub?

Comment: I didn't look into the class so I could be wrong. Try it. The class is called modProgress? Declare a variable of that type. Then use the method. Make sure to use correct arguments like sous said. You should study the code you have so you understand how to use it XD

Answer (score 2):

You are using a [Worksheet object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224506(v=office.11).aspx) where the function is expecting the total number of tasks and a static zero for the current numerical task index.

```
Call modProgress.ShowProgress(mRow, lRow, _
                "Excel is working on Task Number 1", False, _
                "Progress Bar Test")
```

I've used the mRow and lRow in your [For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) to provide the current task and the total number of tasks. This should be close enough although you could reduce both by 1 (mRow starts at 2).